# Errors trying to migrate tables from MariaDB to local MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

New to SQLAlchemy and I am getting an error when I try to copy some tables from this online database (https://relational.fit.cvut.cz/dataset/ConsumerExpenditures):

```
srcEngine = create_engine(    'mariadb+mariadbconnector://guest:relational@relational.fit.cvut.cz:3306/ConsumerExpenditures') 
conn = srcEngine.connect() 
srcEngine._metadata = MetaData(bind=conn, reflect=True)
srcEngine._metadata.reflect(srcEngine)  # get columns from existing table
srcTable = Table('EXPENDITURES', srcEngine._metadata)
```

I am getting an error when execution gets to the MetaData(bind=conn...) call.  Also in the debugger, I look up the srcEngine object and it has to ._metadata attribute.  Is it possible I don't have access to the MetaData from this online database?

As I am new to this, I am not sure how to resolve this problem.  What I want to do is to read the 3 tables from this database and copy them over (same structure and data) over to my local MySQL database.

Comment: If you're getting an error, post the full traceback.

Comment: Hello, I am new to PyCharm IDE also and not sure how to run a full stack trace.

Comment: let me lookup how to do this, hold on

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Connie/PycharmProjects/507-FinalProject/team3-etl-pipeline2.py", line 87, in extract_bls_consumer_expenditures
    srcEngine._metadata = MetaData(bind=conn, reflect=True)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bind'

Comment: The `MetaData()` class doesn't have a `bind` parameter.

Comment: Put the error message in the question, not a comment.

Comment: What version of SQLAlchemy are you using? The `bind` parameter was used up to 1.4, but removed in 2.0.

Comment: See [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/errors.html#a-bind-was-located-via-legacy-bound-metadata-but-since-future-true-is-set-on-this-session-this-bind-is-ignored) for how to rewrite code that uses `MetaData(bind=conn)`

Comment: SQLAlchemy 2.0.0.  let me take a look at your link and read through it, hold on, thanks btw

Comment: I do have one more question.  So I'm trying to copy the database tables from this source to the destination (my local MySQL database).  Then I will have two create_engine() calls and two connect() calls.  But if I call Metadata() without any binding, how does it know which metadata I am trying to get (either the source or destination databases)?

Comment: Also, is this the right sequence of calls in order to copy a database table from one system to another?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily use python to copy databases, I'd use pre-existing export/import tools. E.g. the `mysqldump` CLI tool, or Export and Import in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: See [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_20.html#implicit-and-connectionless-execution-bound-metadata-removed) for migrating bound metadata to 2.0. It looks like you do `src_engine._metadata.create_all(src_engine)`

Comment: It makes more sense to use these tools.  I'm trying to build a ETL pipeline and so now I'm wondering how do people usually automate this part of the pipeline?  (If they don't use the python or another programming language)